# Containable with Condition

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am using containable with CakePHP. My tried code is ...

```php
 public function detail($slug = "") {
        $this->Poet->contain('User.id', 'User.full_name', 'Song.id', 'Song.name', 'Song.name_hindi', 'Song.slug');
        $result = $this->Poet->findBySlug($slug);
        if (!$result) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Poet - ' . $slug));
        }
        pr($result);
        die();
        $this->Poet->id = $result['Poet']['id'];
        $this->set('result', $result);
    }
```

Like this. Now I have Song.status as my association with Song table. I want to fetch only those records that has `status = 1`. Is it possible? Can I select only active records with my piece of code.

Comment: Add more context,show the model association code for both tables..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a normal find

While the magic findBy* methods are handy from time to time, it's a good idea to only use them for trivial queries - your query is nolonger trivial. Instead use a normal find call e.g.:

```
$result = $this->Poet->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id', 
            'full_name'
        ),
        'Song' => array(
            'id', 
            'name',
            'name_hindi',
            'slug',
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'slug' => $slug,
        'Song.status' => 1 // <-
    )
));
```

### Does a Poet hasMany songs?

You don't mention your associations in the question, which is rather fundamental to providing an accurate answer, however it seems likely that a poet has many songs. With that in mind the first example will generate an sql error, as there will be no join between Poet and Song.

Containable does permit [filtering associated data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations) e.g.:

```
$result = $this->Poet->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id', 
            'full_name'
        ),
        'Song' => array(
            'id', 
            'name',
            'name_hindi',
            'slug',
            'Song.status = 1' // <-
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'slug' => $slug
    )
));
```

This will return the poet (whether they have relevant songs or not), and only the songs with a status of "1". You can achieve exactly the same thing by defining the condition in the [association definition](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany) (either directly in the model or by using [bindModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly)).